# Find the word "Dr" (with the "r" in superscript) in MS Word, and replace it with "Dr" (with the "r" in normal font)

Tags: find-and-replace

I am looking for a way to replace all occurrences of "Dr" ("r" **in superscript**) with "Dr" ("r" **not** **in superscript**) in a Word document. Thanks to all.

Comment: So, what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Word should find the text you want to replace regardless of whether a superscript or subscript is used. For example, if I have H<sub>2</sub>O in Word and I search for "H2O" (without quotes), Word will find it:

[image: Microsoft Word Image]

The same will work for D<sup>r</sup> as well. If you're worried about case not matching, you can uncheck "Ignore case" so that the exact case matches:

[image]

You can populate the replace section with "Dr" and it will automatically replace the superscripted "r" with a regular "r"

Example using the find feature to find all instances of D<sup>r</sup>:

[image]

Same file after find and replace was done on all instances:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe the solution was so simple! Best!